# What date format is this : Mon Oct 18 10:26:10 EDT 2021"

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

What date format is the below and how to get this converted to check with current date in Powershell

`Mon Oct 18 10:26:10 EDT 2021`

Comment: I'll presume using a variation to string from the **Get-Date** and **Get-TimeZone** cmdlets. If you want to check the date with powershell. To convert a string to datetime have a look here <https://www.educba.com/powershell-convert-string-to-date/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EDT` means `Eastern Daylight Time (North America)`, which is 4 hours behind from the UTC universal time.

Using that, you could parse it to your local time by first adding the 4 hours offset to get the date in UTC, and finally using method `.ToLocaltime()` on it.

```
[datetime]::ParseExact('Mon Oct 18 10:26:10 EDT 2021', 'ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss \E\D\T yyyy', [cultureinfo]'en-US').AddHours(4).ToLocaltime()
```

On my (Dutch) machine it doesn't seem to matter, but if you want to make **absolutely** sure the parsed-out date is regarded as being UTC (instead of its `.Kind` being set to 'Unspecified', use this:

```
[datetime]::SpecifyKind([datetime]::ParseExact('Mon Oct 18 10:26:10 EDT 2021', 'ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss \E\D\T yyyy', [cultureinfo]'en-US').AddHours(4), 'UTC').ToLocaltime()
```

Comment: Nicely done. Note that it's simpler to pass `'AssumeUniversal'` as the 3rd argument to `[datetime]::ParseExact()`, in which case you'll get a `Local` instance directly (on which you can call `.ToUniversalTime()` if you want a `Utc` instance).

Comment: Thanks Theo.. You are a star...much appreciated.